# firebase.database.ref is not a function React Native / Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I am pretty new to expo and firebase, and I have this error that I have no idea what the issue is. I am trying to fetch photos from firebase database. I know for sure the issue is not with firebase config because I can upload photos into firebase storage.

I suspect the issue is with exporting and importing firebase.

This is the error message I am getting :

> [TypeError: _firebase.db.ref is not a function. (In
> '_firebase.db.ref('users/photos')', '_firebase.db.ref' is undefined)]

Note: I am using firebase v9

App.js file:

```
import { db } from './firebase';

export default function App() {

  async function loadPhotos() {
    try {
      db.ref('users/photos')
        .then(url => {
          console.log('URL: ', url);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
      console.log('Got here');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  }
 ...............
}
```

firebase.js file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '......',
  authDomain: '.....',
  projectId: '....',
  storageBucket: '....',
  messagingSenderId: '....',
  appId: '.....',
  measurementId: '....',
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
export const db = getDatabase();
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the v9 examples in the documentation ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data

Answer (score 0):

In v9 and later of the Firebase SDK, most functionality that was a method on the objects in the past, is now available as a top-level function.

So instead of `db.ref('users/photos')`, you need to do `ref(db, 'users/photos')`.

You're also missing a `get` call, which is how you actually retrieve the data from the reference:

```
get(ref(db, 'users/photos'))
  .then(url => {
    console.log('URL: ', url);
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

This is all pretty well documented in the Firebase documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data), so I recommend keeping that handy. Alternatively you can use the `compat` paths in v9, to make the older syntax work as shown in the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat)/